# Absolute continuity of geometric sum of ergodic random variables

Tags: measure-theory, sequences-and-series, ergodic-theory

I have a stationary ergodic process of random variables $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and a constant $r<1$. Suppose that $\mathbb{E}(\log^+|X_1|)<\infty$. Then the sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^nX_n 
$$
converges, see for example lemma 2.1 of [this link](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aos/1169571804).

**Question:** Assume all the $X_n$ are absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. As explained in the answer of Anthony Quas, the current conditions are not enough to ensure that the sum is then necessarily absolutely continuous too.  Are there extra assumptions that ensure this result?

**Thoughts:** I could assume that all finite dimensional joint distributions are absolutely continuous with respect to the correct dimensional Lebesgue measure. This would ensure that all finite sums $\sum_{n=1}^{N} r^nX_n$ are absolutely continuous. However, I am not sure what then can ensure that the limit is again absolutely continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Ergodicity is definitely not enough. Here is a simple example showing that it goes wrong. Instead of talking about ergodic random variables, I prefer to talk about an ergodic measure-preserving transformation and a function on it.

Let $\Omega=[0,1]^{\mathbb Z}\times\{0,1\}$ and let
$T\colon\Omega\to\Omega$ be defined by
$$
T(\mathbf x,i)=\begin{cases}
(\mathbf x,1)&\text{if $i=0$;}\\
(\sigma(\mathbf x),0)&\text{if $i=1$},
\end{cases}
$$
where $\sigma$ denotes the left shift: $\sigma(\mathbf x)_n=x_{n+1}$. 
An invariant measure is $\lambda^{\mathbb N}\times (\frac 12\delta_0+\frac12 \delta_1)$. This is ergodic (but not mixing).

The function is 
$$
f(x,i)=\begin{cases}
rx_0&\text{if $i=0$;}\\
-x_0&\text{if $i=1$.}
\end{cases}
$$

Now the quantity $S(\mathbf x,i)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(T^n(\mathbf x,i))$ takes the value 0 whenever $i=1$.

If you wanted a mixing example, you could do a variation on the same theme.